# In C, store the result of a for loop in the form of a 2D array

Tags: arrays, c

I'm creating a program that creates all the permutations of 9 in 3 with repetition, this is the code and it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= 9; k++) {
                printf("%d,%d,%d\n", i, j, k);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However instead of printing the permutations I want it to store each permutation as an array of 3 elements in an array of all permutations so a 2D array.

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
int main() {

    int permutas[511][2];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= 9; k++) {
                for (int q = 0; q < 512; q++) {
                    permutas[q][0] = i;
                    permutas[q][1] = j;
                    permutas[q][2] = k;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know how to get it to work. Also if you have any suggestions on how to make the code more efficient feel free to give me the suggestions.

Comment: For an array of size 2 the valid indices are 0 and 1. Your array is not big enough.

Comment: When declaring an array, the size is the number of *elements*, not the top index. Which you seem to think.

Comment: @Matin Gomez-Pablos,  `for(int i=0; i<=9; i++){` iterates 10 times.  I'd expect only 9 iterations needed.

Comment: You do not want that inner loop over `q`, because you want to store each permutation exactly *once* (not 512 times).  You can instead compute `q` from `i`, `j`, and `k` (e.g. `q = 100 * i + 10 * j + k;`), or else declare `q` and set it to zero outside the loop nest, incrementing it once on each iteration of the innermost loop.

Comment: There are 1000 permutations of the digits 0..9 (10³); your array needs to be `int permutas[1000][3];` to get all the results, and `int permutas[512][3];` to record the first 512 permutations.  If you wanted 1..9 (9³), you'd need an array of size 729 — and you'd have to change your loops to start at 1.  As it is, `permutas[q][2]` is accessing 'out of bounds' (mostly harmlessly), but when `q == 511`, `permutas[q][2]` is accessing way out of bounds (undefined behaviour, and quite possibly not harmless).  If the array dimension is 511, the maximum safe index is 510.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program produces the same output as the first code snippet which you posted above -- the part which "works."

You need a 1000 element array, 10^3 elements, to hold the values and a counter to store the items properly.

```
/* 

*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int array[1000][3];

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k) {
                array[count][0] = i;
                array[count][1] = j;
                array[count][2] = k;
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        printf("%d,%d,%d\n", array[i][0], array[i][1], array[i][2]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```